# Why does a "&&=" Operator not exist?

Tags: java, operators, logic, bitwise-operators

`(a && b)` has the same value as `(a & b)`, but with && the expression `b` is not executed if `a` is false. In Java there is also an operator &=. 
`a &= b` is the same as `a = a & b`.

Question: Why isn't there an operator &&=, at least in Java. Is there some reason why I would not make sense to have it, or is it simply that no one cares or needs it?