# What does |= in Java / Android mean? (bit-wise OR assignment)

Tags: java, android, bitwise-operators

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Shortcut “or-assignment” (|=) operator in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2486472/shortcut-or-assignment-operator-in-java)

I found the following example code in the Android SDK docs:

```
    boolean retValue = false;
    retValue |= mActionBarHelper.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    retValue |= super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
```

Can anyone show me equivalent code, to demonstrate what this does?

Note: I assume the method calls return a boolean value, so I like to see an example what this looks like as an if-else construct.

Comment: @GregKopff:  It *is* a bitwise OR, not a logical OR.

Comment: @Makoto: I didn't think there was a defined bit representation of a boolean data type.

Comment: @GregKopff:  A bitwise OR means that you're taking two sets of bits, and keeping the bits set high if and only if the bit in the same place is set high.  Example:  1001 | 0110 = 1111.  [Check Wikipedia for more info.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#OR)

Comment: @Makoto: Well understood - and for bytes, chars, shorts, ints and longs that have a defined bit representation, that makes sense. Sure a boolean can be considered 1 bit (the language uses a byte to store it), but it doesn't have a bit representation in the same way the other data types do.  You can't cast a boolean to a byte and get 0x00 / 0x01 out.  Yes, a bitwise operation is easy enough to conceptualise on a single bit - but for the reasons above, I'm "surprised" by it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shorthand for `or` with myself and assign to me, though it is non-short circuit `or` instead of logical `or`. As it is available as a short version of assigning and or:ing sometimes used anyway with booleans, as there is no ||=.
But important note: in this case it *will* call both methods even though retValue might already be `true`

So equivalent (logic wise) statements can be several, but some would be:

```
boolean a = mActionBarHelper.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
boolean b = super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
boolean retValue =  a || b;
```

or

```
boolean retValue = mActionBarHelper.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
retValue = super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu) || retValue;
```

Answer (score 8):

| applied to a boolean is just a simple boolean OR.

```
boolean retValue = false;
retValue = retValue | mActionBarHelper.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
retValue = retValue | super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
```