# Java boolean |= operator

Tags: java, operators, specifications, boolean-expression, compound-assignment

Recently I saw a code using this:

```
boolean val = something();
val |= somethingElse();
```

Interesting part is |= (binary like) operator made on boolean primitive type.

It surprised me that |= exist for boolean, as if it was integer type, and searched Java specification for this operator, but could not find any.

I'd be curious if right operand is evaluated if left value already is true.

Can someone point me to Java specification of this?

Comment: It is merely val = val | somethingElse(); // somethingElse() expected to return boolean. It is a standard OR

Comment: @SudhanshuUmalkar OP knows that, he asks for specification in a document.

Comment: answer is here dudes: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2486472/544983

Comment: I thought there is only || for boolean expressions, so I would expect operator like ||= .  Does it make sense to make binary | on boolean?

Comment: No shortcut evaluation, though not mentioned explicitly. Only at || the shortcut logic is mentioned explicitly.

Comment: @Sudhanshu it's not a standard OR, it's a bitwise OR operator (as opposed to a boolean operator). It is also an aggressive operator, as opposed a short-circuit operator (such as the boolean operator).

Answer (score 36, accepted):

From the JLS:

> [**15.26.2. Compound Assignment Operators**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26.2)
>
> A compound assignment expression of the form `E1 op= E2` is equivalent to `E1 = (T) ((E1) op (E2))`, where `T` is the type of `E1`, except that `E1` is evaluated only once.
>
> [**15.22.2. Boolean Logical Operators `&`, `^`, and `|`**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.22.2)
>
> When both operands of a `&`, `^`, or `|` operator are of type `boolean` or `Boolean`, then the type of the bitwise operator expression is `boolean`. In all cases, the operands are subject to unboxing conversion (§5.1.8) as necessary.
>
> For `|`, the result value is false if both operand values are false; otherwise, the result is true.

This means that

```
val |= somethingElse();
```

is strictly equivalent to

```
val = val | somethingElse();
```

(assuming `somethingElse()` returns `boolean` or `Boolean`).

> I'd be curious if right operand is evaluated if left value already is true.

Yes, it would be evaluated, since `|` does not short-circuit:

> [**15.7.2. Evaluate Operands before Operation**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.7.2)
>
> The Java programming language guarantees that every operand of an operator (except the conditional operators `&&`, `||`, and `? :`) appears to be fully evaluated before any part of the operation itself is performed.
>
> [**15.24. Conditional-Or Operator `||`**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.24)
>
> Thus, `||` computes the same result as `|` on `boolean` or `Boolean` operands. It differs only in that the right-hand operand expression is evaluated conditionally rather than always.

Comment: `val |= somethingElse();` has no equivalent in Kotlin. I wonder why...

Answer (score 4):

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.22.2 for the definition of `|`. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26.2 for the defintion of `|=`. The definitions are just what you would think.

What surprises me is the lack of a `||=` operator.

Answer (score 3):

The bitwise logic operators will have the same effect of "normal" logic operators on booleans.

From [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.22) 15.22:

> When both operands of a &, ^, or | operator are of type boolean or
>   Boolean, then the type of the bitwise operator expression is boolean.
>   In all cases, the operands are subject to unboxing conversion (§5.1.8)
>   as necessary.
>
> For &, the result value is true if both operand values are true;
>   otherwise, the result is false.
>
> For ^, the result value is true if the operand values are different;
>   otherwise, the result is false.
>
> For |, the result value is false if both operand values are false;
>   otherwise, the result is true.

The only real difference is that bitwise operators cant be used to short-circuit evaluation.

For example, this code will throw `NullPointerException`:

```
Boolean b1 = new Boolean(true);
Boolean b2 = null;
if (b1 || b2) {
    //no null pointer here;
}
if (b1 | b2) {
    //null pointer here;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
>>I'd be curious if right operand is evaluated if left value already is true.
```

Bitwise operators (like `|`, `&`, ..) evaluate both sides, before completion.

Logical operators (like `&&`, `||`, ..) can skip the evaluation of the second part in some cases. This is called `short-circuit`.

Answer (score -1):

It is not binary it's an "OR" logic statement means

```
 val |= {something else}
```

is same as the Boolean expression:

```
val == val or {something else}
```

which is inclusive or ( the regular or used in mathematics expressions and computer science)

In some programming languages or is noted by two || signs and in some by one | one of them is SQL and all database languages that I know of DTD JSON etc..

Comment: `|` is not the conditional OR (`||`), it's the bitwise OR. So `val |= something` is the same as `val = val | something`.