# Why &= operator doesn't work the same as &&

Tags: java, boolean, operators

I'm just curious how java works. Can someone explain why `getBoolean` is called in Case 1 and not called in Case 2?

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("---------- Case 1 ----------");
        boolean b = false;
        b &= getBoolean(true);

        System.out.println("---------- Case 2 ----------");
        b = false;
        b = b && getBoolean(true);
    }

    private static boolean getBoolean(boolean bool) {
        System.out.println("getBoolean(" + bool + ") was called\n");
        return bool;
    }

}
```

Output:

```
---------- Case 1 ----------
getBoolean(true) was called

---------- Case 2 ----------
```

Comment: logical versus bitwise AND

Comment: It works like the `&` operator does. Every compound operator works like the equivalent operator without the `=` - so `+=` is like `+`, `-=` is like `-`, etc. Why would you expect `&=` to be like `&&`?

Comment: @Sneftel - there is no difference between "logical" and "bitwise" for booleans, because they are just one active bit.  What matters here is that `&&` is short-circuit, but `&` and `&=` are not.

Comment: That was pretty much my point, yes.

Comment: Really?  Because it's not what you said at all.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Shortcut "or-assignment" (|=) operator in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2486472/shortcut-or-assignment-operator-in-java)

Comment: & does not short circuit *because* it is treated as a bitwise op. This behavior was copied directly from C; Java dropped some of the integer-ness of booleans (and most of the boolean-ness of integers), but kept the ability to perform this integer op on booleans because of the short-circuiting difference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`b &= a` is a shortcut to `b = b & a` not to `b = b && a`

It is because of the difference between `&` and `&&` operators.

- The `&` operator always evaluates both sides of conditions.
- The `&&` operator evaluates the second only if needed.

So, `getBoolean(true)` will not run in the 2nd case.

Comment: +1, adding the reason, `b &= a` is equal to `b = b & a` not `b = b && a`

Answer (score 4):

In Case 2 `getBoolean(true);` is not evaluated, because the `&&` is a short-circuit operator, e.g. if the expression will be `false` it stops evaluating

Case 1 just sets the result of the `getBoolean()` method to the `b` variable.

---

Update, thanks to @KisHan:

Note that `b &= a` is equal to `b = b & a` and not `b = b && a`

Comment: This can be added in answer, `b &= a` is equal to `b = b & a` not `b = b && a`

Answer (score 3):

In second case `b` is `false` and for `&&` if first condition is false it won't move ahead.

```
 b = b && getBoolean(true);//b is false
```

So `&&`(Logical AND) first checks the left side of the operation, if it's `true` **than** it `continues`  to the right side.

While `&`(Bitwise AND) operator evaluates both sides of expression as it's [bitwise](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation)  AND operator.As it performs AND operation between leftside and right side.

So in first case it will be

```
b = b & getBoolean(true);//will perform AND operation to evaluate Expression
```

Answer (score 2):

in first case it's bitwise and trying to get the assigned value (`getBoolean()`).

in second case the && does a [`short circuit evaluation`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation). Where if first expression is false then the second won't evaluate.

> in which the second argument is only executed or evaluated if the first argument does not suffice to determine the value of the expression:

```
b = b && getBoolean(true); // b already false and there is no use even getBoolean(true) is true or false , because the result is already false as b is false.
```

Answer (score 1):

`&` means bitwise AND: on a bit-by-bit level, it sets the output to `true` if both of the input bits were true. `&&` means logical AND: if both inputs are truthy, the expression returns true. `&&` is also short-circuiting (stops evaluation and returns false immediately if the first input is falsy), which is what you're seeing here.

Comment: They're booleans - it doesn't make sense to distinguish between "bitwise" and "logical" for booleans, because there is only one meaningful bit.

Comment: @DavidWallace it doesn't make sense to talk about a "short-circuiting bitwise operation." The OP obviously does not understand the difference between a bitwise and logical AND, any answer that doesn't explain what's going on here is incomplete.

Comment: If you understand bitwise vs logical, the fact that `&` does not short circuit follows immediately as a consequence. If you don't explain what a bitwise AND is, then it doesn't make any sense. It's as if the OP asked "I don't understand why it's easier to drive nails with a hammer than a screwdriver," and you didn't explain what a screw is.

Comment: There IS no difference between bitwise and logical if there's only one bit.  `&&` is bitwise AND logical AND short-circuiting.  `&` is bitwise AND logical AND not short-circuiting.  Talking about "bitwise" and "logical" for booleans is a complete red herring.

Comment: `&` and `&&` are completely different operations, the fact that booleans are only a single bit is not the point. This is a special case of `any_truthy_value & function_call()`, and a complete answer explains the general case.