# What's the point of the compound comparison operators?

Tags: java, comparison, operators, shortcut

I have read that `b1 |= b2` is the shortcut equivalent to `b1 = b1 | b2`. My question is really two-fold:

Isn't "=" an assignment operator rather than a comparison operator? If so, what does it do in this context?

Or, is it a comparison operator here and what scenario exists where you would need to compare a variable to itself (i.e. `b1 = b1`)?

(I realize this is probably the newbie-est newb question to ask, but I've only got informal experience writing bash scripts and no educational background in programming. Be kind. ;)

Note: this is in reference to the question here: [Shortcut "or-assignment" (|=) operator in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2486472/shortcut-or-assignment-operator-in-java/2486574#2486574)

Comment: `|=` isn't a compound comparison operator.

Comment: There are no compound comparison operators, only compound assignment operators.

Comment: Is this a boolean thing where b1 will be true if either b1 or b2 is true?

Comment: @BackSlash how do you think you could use a short-circuiting form of `|=`? I mean, suppose `||=` did exist, how would you use it in a meaningful way?

Comment: @BackSlash That was the explanation I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: @BackSlash Wrong. The pipe operator `|` is used for both bitwise and logical OR. The double pipe operator is used only for logical, and the difference between `a | b` and `a || b` when the operators are boolean is that the first is not short-circuiting, and the second is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many operators in Java. But 'Compound comparison operator' is not one of them. You should read Java basics from a good book like 'Head first Java'.

To answer this particular question, `b1 |= b2` is compound assignment.

1. `=` assigns the the result of `b1|b2` to LHS operand i.e `b1`.
2. Since it is clear now that it is an `assignment` operator not comparison, the result of `b1 |= b1` will be same as `b1 = b1|b1`.

(Note `|` here is the logical `OR` between two numbers not `||` which is a conditional operator. `|` and `||` have different meanings)

HTH.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Did you mean to write `b1 = b1|b2` rather than `b1 = b1|b1`?

Comment: I meant `b1 = b1|b1`, in response to your second question where you had doubt about same variable being used on both sides.