# Why doesn't c++ have &&= or ||= for booleans?

Tags: c++, boolean-operations

Is there a ["very bad thing"](http://xkcd.com/292/) that can happen `&&=` and `||=` were used as syntactic sugar for `bool foo = foo && bar` and `bool foo = foo || bar`?

Comment: See this other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2324549/why-doesnt-java-have-compound-assignment-versions-of-the-conditional-and-and-con
That one's about Java, but sharing the C lineage, the same arguments mostly apply.

Comment: Basically, just c++ doesn't have it b/c they didn't put it in - languages like Ruby has it. boo...

Comment: But in Ruby, isn't `x ||= y` roughly equivalent to C++ `x = x ? x : y;` for any type? In other words, "set to y if not already set". That's considerably more useful than C or C++ `x ||= y`, which (barring operator overloading) would do "set x to `(bool)y` unless already set". I'm not anxious to add another operator for that, it seems a bit feeble. Just write `if (!x) x = (bool)y`. But then, I don't really use `bool` variables enough to want extra operators that are only really useful with that one type.

Comment: I'm sure the primary reason C++ doesn't have `&&=` or `||=` is simply that C doesn't have them.  I'm reasonably sure the reason C doesn't have them is that the functionality wasn't deemed beneficial enough.

Comment: Also, being ultra-pedantic, the notation `bool foo = foo || bar;` would invoke undefined behaviour because `foo` is not initialized prior to the evaluation of `foo || bar`.  Of course, this is intended to be something like `bool foo = …initialization…; …;  foo = foo || bar;` and the question then stands as valid.

Comment: C probably didn't have them because C didn't have `bool`, and these operations only *really* make sense for `bool` type.

Answer (score 100, accepted):

A `bool` may only be `true` or `false` in C++. As such, using `&=` and `|=` is relatively safe (even though I don’t particularly like the notation). True, they will perform bit operations rather than logical operations (and thus they won’t short-circuit) but these bit operations follow a well-defined mapping, which is effectively equivalent to the logical operations, ***as long as* both operands are of type `bool`**.<sup>1</sup>

Contrary to what other people have said here, a `bool` in C++ must never have a different value such as `2`. When assigning that value to a `bool`, it will be converted to `true` as per the standard.

The only way to get an invalid value into a `bool` is by using `reinterpret_cast` on pointers:

```
int i = 2;
bool b = *reinterpret_cast<bool*>(&i);
b |= true; // MAY yield 3 (but doesn’t on my PC!)
```

But since this code results in undefined behaviour anyway, we may safely ignore this potential problem in conforming C++ code.

---

<sup>1</sup> Admittedly this is a rather big caveat as Angew’s comment illustrates:

```
bool b = true;
b &= 2; // yields `false`.
```

The reason is that `b & 2` performs integer promotion such that the expression is then equivalent to `static_cast<int>(b) & 2`, which results in `0`, which is then converted back into a `bool`. So it’s true that the existence of an `operator &&=` would improve type safety.

Comment: But the && and || operators will work on anything that *converts* to bool, not just bool.

Comment: They don't do the same thing, even on bools. `||` and `&&` shortcut, i.e. the second argument isn't operand if the first operand is `true` (resp. `false` for `&&`). `|`, `&`, `|=` and `&=` always evaluate both operands.

Comment: @nikie: I didn’t say that they did the same. And do you really want to short-circuit an assignment such as `a &&= b`? I think that’s asking for trouble.

Comment: In fact, if you try to do a `switch` on the above `b`, it is likely you end up in `default:` even if you have both true and false branches.

Comment: @Johannes: The UB case? Yes, that’s possible. But I’ve tested this and on my PC (OS X 10.5, GCC 4.4.2) it actually doesn’t – which kind of surprised me, too.

Comment: this doesn't answer the question of why &&= and ||= are not c++ operators.

Comment: @ethang I chose to answer the question in the actual text body rather than the one in the title. Admittedly, it’s hard to know whether that was appropriate since the title and the body of the question contradicted each other. Yet the OP seems to be happy. At any rate, there’s no real answer to the question in the title, except “because.” — Nobody made a corresponding proposal to the standards committee, or any such proposal was vetoed.

Comment: In addition to @dan04 's comment (from 6 years ago...) - bools very often convert to ints for all sorts of reasons, and the &&= would make sure everything is boolean again

Comment: It's **not** safe to use `&=` for a left-hand side of type `bool`, because it's perfectly possible for the right-hand side to be of type other than `bool` (such as `islower` or another C stdlib function which returns nonzero for true value). If we had the hypothetical `&&=`, it would probably force the right-hand side to convert to `bool`, which `&=` does not. In other words, `bool b = true; b &= 2;` results in `b == false`.

Comment: @Angew That’s why I wrote “*as long as* both operands *are* indeed of type `bool`.” But you’re right that implicit conversion (and in particular integer promotion) make this usage less safe than a hypothetical `&&=`. I’ll add a footnote to my answer.

Comment: Downvoted because your highlighting doesn't include "as long as both operands are indeed of type `bool`". One could read just the highlighted part and bring home the wrong message.

Comment: @Antonio Tough crowd. 

Comment: Why is this the top answer?  How is this even an answer of any sort?

Comment: @Apollys What are you missing from it? Speculations about the language designers’ motives? These are generally seen as unreliable, subjective and off-topic here. We don’t know *why*. Case in point, olibre’s answer is *pure speculation* despite sounding authoritative. By contrast, this answer gives technical reasons for why having them isn’t all that useful, which *might* be the underlying cause.

Comment: Note that your `reinterpret_cast<>()` in this statement `bool b = *reinterpret_cast<bool*>(&i);` is not going to do what you think on Big Endian machines. You would need to check the size of `bool` (probably 1 byte, probably 8 on a CRAY, though) and based on that use an `int` type of the right size.

Comment: @AlexisWilke Absolutely. And the code is UB anyway. I could have made it more “portable” by abstracting away the size of a boolean (and endianness) but that would have distracted from the point I was making.

Answer (score 51):

`&&` and `&` have different semantics: `&&` will not evaluate the second operand if the first operand is `false`. i.e. something like

```
flag = (ptr != NULL) && (ptr->member > 3);
```

is safe, but

```
flag = (ptr != NULL) & (ptr->member > 3);
```

is not, although both operands are of type `bool`.

The same is true for `&=` and `|=`:

```
flag = CheckFileExists();
flag = flag && CheckFileReadable();
flag = flag && CheckFileContents();
```

will behave differently than:

```
flag = CheckFileExists();
flag &= CheckFileReadable();
flag &= CheckFileContents();
```

Comment: all the more reason to have &&= in my opinion. =P

Comment: This isn't really an answer though.

Answer (score 37):

## Short answer

All the operators `+=`, `-=`, `*=`,  `/=`, `&=`, `|=`... are arithmetic and provide same expectation:

```
x &= foo()  // We expect foo() be called whatever the value of x
```

However, operators `&&=` and `||=` would be logical, and these operators might be error-prone because many developers would expect `foo()` be always called in `x &&= foo()`.

```
bool x;
// ...
x &&= foo();           // Many developers might be confused
x = x && foo();        // Still confusing but correct
x = x ? foo() : x;     // Understandable
x = x ? foo() : false; // Understandable
if (x) x = foo();      // Obvious
```

- Do we really need to make C/C++ even more complex to get a shortcut for `x = x && foo()`?
- Do we really want to obfuscate more the cryptic statement `x = x && foo()`?
  Or do we want to write meaningful code like `if (x) x = foo();`?

---

## Long answer

### Example for `&&=`

If `&&=` operator was available, then this code:

```
bool ok = true; //becomes false when at least a function returns false
ok &&= f1();
ok &&= f2(); //we may expect f2() is called whatever the f1() returned value
```

is equivalent to:

```
bool ok = true;
if (ok) ok = f1();
if (ok) ok = f2(); //f2() is called only when f1() returns true
```

This first code is **error-prone** because many developers would think `f2()` is always called whatever the `f1()` returned value. It is like writing `bool ok = f1() && f2();` where `f2()` is called only when `f1()` returns `true`.

- If the developer actually wants `f2()` to be called only when `f1()` returns `true`, therefore the second code above is less error-prone.
- Else (the developer wants `f2()` to be always called), `&=` is sufficient:

### Example for `&=`

```
bool ok = true;
ok &= f1();
ok &= f2(); //f2() always called whatever the f1() returned value
```

Moreover, it is easier for compiler to optimize this above code than that below one:

```
bool ok = true;
if (!f1())  ok = false;
if (!f2())  ok = false;  //f2() always called
```

### Compare `&&` and `&`

We may wonder whether the operators `&&` and `&` give the same result when applied on `bool` values?

Let's check using the following C++ code:

```
#include <iostream>

void test (int testnumber, bool a, bool b)
{
   std::cout << testnumber <<") a="<< a <<" and b="<< b <<"\n"
                "a && b = "<< (a && b)  <<"\n"
                "a &  b = "<< (a &  b)  <<"\n"
                "======================"  "\n";
}

int main ()
{
    test (1, true,  true);
    test (2, true,  false);
    test (3, false, false);
    test (4, false, true);
}
```

Output:

```
1) a=1 and b=1
a && b = 1
a &  b = 1
======================
2) a=1 and b=0
a && b = 0
a &  b = 0
======================
3) a=0 and b=0
a && b = 0
a &  b = 0
======================
4) a=0 and b=1
a && b = 0
a &  b = 0
======================
```

### Conclusion

Therefore **YES** we can replace `&&` by `&` for `bool` values  ;-) 
So better use `&=` instead of `&&=`. 
We can consider `&&=` as useless for booleans.

### Same for `||=`

> operator `|=` is also less **error-prone** than `||=`

If a developer wants `f2()` be called only when `f1()` returns `false`, instead of:

```
bool ok = false;
ok ||= f1();
ok ||= f2(); //f2() is called only when f1() returns false
ok ||= f3(); //f3() is called only when f1() or f2() return false
ok ||= f4(); //f4() is called only when ...
```

I advice the following more understandable alternative:

```
bool ok = false;
if (!ok) ok = f1();
if (!ok) ok = f2();
if (!ok) ok = f3();
if (!ok) ok = f4();
// no comment required here (code is enough understandable)
```

or if you prefer *all in one line* style:

```
// this comment is required to explain to developers that 
// f2() is called only when f1() returns false, and so on...
bool ok = f1() || f2() || f3() || f4();
```

Comment: What if I actually want this behaviour? That the right hand expression is not executed if the left hand expression is wrong. It is annoying to write the variables two times, like `success = success && DoImportantStuff()`

Comment: My advice is to write `if(success) success = DoImportantStuff()`. If the statement `success &&= DoImportantStuff()` was allowed, many developers would think `DoImportantStuff()` is always called whatever the value of `success`. 
Hope this answers what you wonder... I have also improved many parts of my answer. Please tell me if my answer is more understandable now? (about your comment purpose) Cheers, See you ;-)

Comment: "If the statement `success &&= DoImportantStuff()` was allowed, many developers would think `DoImportantStuff()` is always called whatever the value of success."  
You can say that about `if (success && DoImportantStuff())` though.  
As long as they remember the logic behind the if syntax they should have no trouble with `&&=`.

Comment: I don't see how people may assume that `f1()` always evaluates in `ok &&=  f(1)`  but won't assume it always evaluates in `ok = ok && f(1)` . Seems just as likely to me.

Comment: Hi @einpoklum Good question and I think I should improve my answer... I mean when you see a statement `ok=f();` or `ok+=f();` or `ok%=f();` or `ok&=f();` you expect some value will be stored in variable `ok`. Therefore most of brains also expect `ok&&=f();` will store a value in `ok`. Do you feel what I mean? There is also something I do not mention yet in the answer: **sequence points**. The statement `ok=f();` has one sequence point: the final `;` The statement `ok=ok&&f();` has two sequence points: `&&` and `;`. Operators `=` cannot be a sequence point in languages C and C++.

Comment: I actually expect  `v1 += e2` to be the syntactic sugar equivalent of `v1 = v1 + e1` for variable v1 and expression e2. Just a shorthand notation, that's all.

Comment: "operator |= is also less error-prone than ||= " , Really? People make mistakes either ways.  I just discovered an error in my code where I found that my assumption that line ok |= f(); will not evaluate 'f' if ok is already true is false.

Comment: Hi @aruns. Thanks for for feedback :-) Most developers will think the function `f()` will always be called in both cases: `ok |= f();` and `ok ||= f();` whatever the value of `ok`. This is only exact for `ok |= f();`. I am very surprised that you thought `f()` will not be called if `ok` was already `true`. Do not forget: *you do not write code to be understandable for the compiler, you first write code to be understandable by your colleagues*. Therefore I propose this more readable syntax: `if (! ok) f();`. Do you agree? Cheers ;-)

Comment: This assumes that programmers will expect `x = x || y` and `x = x && y` to have different behaviours than `x ||= y` and `x &&= y`, which I... can see being a plausible assumption in some cases, but _really_ don't like. xD

Comment: Best answer by far (really the only one that addresses the question).

Comment: The first part of the long answer is wrong.  They are not equivalent.  It is entirely reasonable to not want the short circuit and only do something if any one of the expressions return true: `b &&= dostuff1(); b &&= dostuff2(); ... if (b) set_dirty();` for example.

Answer (score 0):

short circuiting is important, and the semantics are straightforward. A &&= B would be syntactic sugar for A = A && B.

The concept of monadic programming was not widespread in the early days of K&R, so it seems the best explanation is K&R didn't think it was important, and like the QWERTY keyboard, we've lived with it ever since.