Idiomatic alternative for operator logical-and-equals?
C++ has 'accumulator' operations for arithmetic (+,-,*,/) , and for bitwise operations AND and OR - but not for logical operations.
Now, in our code, we sometimes need to conjunct many boolean values - just like we need to sum up multiple arithmetic value. But while we can write:
int sum { 0 };
sum += foo();
sum += (bar * baz);
sum += quux() ? 5 : 2;
for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
    sum += arr[get_index(i)];
}

we seem to be relegated to writing
bool all_ok { true };
all_ok = all_ok and (foo() == GoodFoo);
all_ok = all_ok and (bar * baz > 3);
all_ok = all_ok and quux();
for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
    all_ok = all_ok and (arr[get_index(i)] == expected(i));
}

which is annoying. What is the most common (well-regarded) idiom we should use instead?

Did you simplify it too much or are there a fixed number (or as I think you know I'm looking for) a compile time number of expressions?

I believe (?) you can use &= and |= on Boolean values. Am I mistaken about that?

Please widen it to cover the full expression if there is one not shown. If the expression is known at compile time, it'll result in very different code than if it will be constructed as a result of runtime data.

@templatetypedef: I believe you are correct, but note that they do not short circuit.

What happened here? Closed for being "opinion-based"?  It just needs some details.

@FredLarson They will short-circuit if it's a compile-time expression (properly formed).

@templatetypedef: 1. Is that what you know to be commonly done? 2. Isn't that a bit confusing?

@TedLyngmo: I'm not sure I follow. Which full expression do you mean? Anyway, added a loop in there, although it really doesn't matter. Also, the idea isn't putting these statements one after the other arbitrarily, typically there would be more code between them. Shall I add // ... etc. lines?

@TedLyngmo I think opinion-based is correct, given that the headline is asking for the "best" idiom and not alternatives. I believe any objective "best" idioms already exist as dupes, leaving only the subjective "best" idioms.

@sweenish: Rephrased the title.

No matter the close reason, I'm quite sure this is a dupe.

@MarkRansom: I would be love to close this as a dupe - since that would mean there's a good answer to this question somewhere. But you have to find it first...

@einpoklum My first thought was "can this be made into a constant expression somehow". If what you present as a loop is in fact static information it is more fun :)
Anyway, glad it reopened.

Is this a duplicate of Self logical and?

@einpoklum I’ve seen that pattern used before. I can’t say whether it’s “commonly done” or “confusing” but I haven’t seen any evidence to the contrary.

Is an indexed loop a requirement

Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2488406/why-doesnt-c-have-or-for-booleans

@JaMiT: Very close to being a dupe of that. Unfortunately, the focus of that question was slightly more limited; plus, it was asked in 2012 when even C++11 wasn't widely adopted.

Logical operators (!, && and ||) are mostly a C legacy from the era that bool was not a built-in type. Their main purpose is conversion of integrals to bool and short-circuit chain of evaluation:
auto f=[]{
    std::println("not invoked on right hand of '||', if left is true");
    return false;
};

auto g=[]{
    std::println("not invoked on right hand of '&&', if left is false");
    return true;
};

auto log_and = f() && g();// g not invoked
auto log_or  = g() || f();// f not invoked
assert((not log_and));
assert((log_or));

bool is an integral type, with all the integral bitwise operators (~, &, |, ^, <<, and >>). Their effects are similar to logical operators (except for short-circuiting):
auto bit_and = f() & g();// both invoked
auto bit_or  = g() | f();// both invoked
assert((log_and == bit_and));
assert((log_or  == bit_or));

Like other arithmetic operators, logical bitwise binary operators(&, |, and ^) too have compound assignment counterparts(binary ≠ unary, means it takes two operands).
If your focus is on arrays and ranges, ever since C++11, std::all_of, std::any_of and std::none_of have been part of <algorithm> header. You could also use C++23 std::ranges::fold_left, std::ranges::fold_right, and more from the same header, or the C++98
std::accumulate and C++17 std::reduce from <numeric> header. These library algorithms usually need a lambda as their accumulating binary operator for the last argument. Most of them also need an initial value too, but there are some other algorithms in std::ranges that do not need an initial value under the assumption of none-empty input ranges.

all_of, any_of and such are useful when you apply a logical operation uniformly, in terms of the code for the expressions. The example in my question clarified that I'm not limiting myself simply to such cases - of ranges and arrays. It is a bit as if you suggested I stop using += in C++ and only used accumulate and reduce...

Nope! the first paragraph suggests using bitwise operators on bool objects. Keep logic operators for short-circuiting and/or converting arithmetic to bool with less syntactic noise.

@einpoklum you forced to write a lot more.
