# &&= in C#? (boolean expression)

Tags: c#, boolean-operations

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why are there no ||= or &&= operators?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6346001/why-are-there-no-or-operators)

By pure accident I found out today that

```
 a &= GetBool();
```

is NOT the same as

```
 a = a && GetBool();
```

I must have misunderstood that for years. In the first Example, "`GetBool()`" is executed even if "a" is false. In the second, it isn't.

Is there anything to achieve something like "&&=" in C#?

Comment: @Soohjun: That should be `false` instead of `true`.

Comment: I believe Eric blogged on why `&&=` is not available .....Ahh here it is http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2012/04/19/null-is-not-false-part-three.aspx

Comment: See [this answer by Eric Lippert](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6346001/why-are-there-no-or-operators).

Comment: @HenkHolterman: Bitwise and boolean is exactly the same when the type is a bit/boolean.

Comment: @HenkHolterman: I think I am confusing myself, with my own comments. Deleting :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e669ax02%28VS.80%29.aspx):

> An expression using the &= assignment operator, such as
>
> x &= y
>
> is equivalent to
>
> x = x & y
>
> except that x is only evaluated once. The & operator performs a
>   bitwise logical AND operation on integral operands and logical AND on
>   bool operands.

I would say, to avoid evaluation of y when not necessary, use

```
x = x && y
```

and to avoid evaluation of x twice (whatever this means), use

```
x &= y
```

You can't combine both.

Micro-optimized (at least for a theoretical case), it would be:

```
if (x) x = y;
```

You don't need to do anything if x is already `false`.

Comment: "evaluated once" is meant for more complex cases, for instance if you have `x[i+3] = x[i+3] & y;` Then `i+3` is calculated twice, obviously!

Comment: @Mr Lister: This makes sense, I didn't consider this. There are also properties, where you can use the &= operator, which may have an arbitrary complex implementation (if this is a good design aside).

Answer (score 6):

> Is there anything to achieve something like "&&=" in C#?

Well, you can write

```
a = a && getBool();
```

instead... I can't think of many situations where I'd actually *want* to do anything different, to be honest. Even the above is pretty rare, IME.

There's no compound assignment operator defined for `&&`, `||` or `??` (which are the obvious "short-circuiting" operators). See section 7.17 of the C# 4 spec for the full list of compound assignment operators, and section 7.17.2 for more details about what *exactly* compound assignment does.