# Using &= on boolean values in C#

Tags: c#, boolean, operators, short-circuiting

I have a method in C# called `SendEvent` that returns a `bool` which represents if it was successful or not. I want to loop through a number of objects and call `SendEvent` on them all, and in the end, have a result variable that is a `bool`, that is `true` if all `SendEvent` calls succeeded, and `false` if at least one failed.

At first I did this:

```
bool result = true;
for (int i = 0; i < myObjects.Length; i++)
{
    result = result && myObjects[i].SendEvent();
}
```

But that will cause that the `SendEvent` will not be called on subsequent objects if one fails, as the right hand side of the `&&` operator won't be executed if result is `false`.

So I turned it around, to:

```
bool result = true;
for (int i = 0; i < myObjects.Length; i++)
{
    result = myObjects[i].SendEvent() && result;
}
```

But I found that somewhat ugly. Can I use the bitwise `&=` operator to always execute the `SendEvent` call, and set the value of result, like this?

```
bool result = true;
for (int i = 0; i < myObjects.Length; i++)
{
    result &= myObjects[i].SendEvent();
}
```

How does the `&=` work on boolean values? Will it execute both sides of the operator? What will end up in the result variable?

Comment: It is not `&=`, it is `&&=`. `&=` is the operator for logical and.

Comment: @dcg: no, the OP wants the event to be called, and `&` is defined on `bool`s as well.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem so `&=` is the same as `&&=` with bool?

Comment: @dcg: [`&&=` does **not exists**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6346001/why-are-there-no-or-operators).

Comment: Which makes sense, since such a hypothetical `&&=` would not guarantee the code behind it would even be executed.

Comment: Is it only important *if any* failed or do you later have to fix and find out *which* failed? If the latter, then you should keep track of that.

Comment: @Fildor No, I don't have to know which specific call failed, only if one of them failed or if they all succeeded.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As you can read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4163509/67579), **both `&` and `&&` are defined for `bool`s** as "*logical and*", but **`&&` will *short-circuit:*** in case the first operand is `false` the expression on the right will not be evaluated. Regardless what the outcome of the expression on the right is, the result of the `&&` expression will remain `false`. This is usually a "performance hack" in the first place, but if the right expression has *side-effects*, could throw an exception, etc., it is something you have to take into account. The same happens for the `||` operator if the first operand is `true`.

So if you want to **evaluate both sides first**, you can indeed use:

```
result = result & myObjects[i].SendEvent();
```

or shorter:

```
result &= myObjects[i].SendEvent();
```

## Background

As is written in the [*language specifications*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2a723cdk.aspx#Anchor_0):

> The operation
>
> ```
> x && y
> ```
>
> corresponds to the operation
>
> ```
> x & y
> ```
>
> except that if `x` is `false`, `y` is not evaluated, because the
>   result of the AND operation is `false` no matter what the value of `y`
>   is. This is known as "*short-circuit*" evaluation.

Note that there is **no `&&=` operator** (at least at the time I am writing this). This looks *reasonable* since usually with an `..=` operator, you would expect that the operand is first evaluated and then some operation is done on the variable to the left. Of course it is all a matter of style and taste, but I would reason that a hypothetical `&&=` does not give "*enough hints*" that the right operand will not be called in all cases.

Comment: Thank you, this is a great answer! :)

Answer (score 6):

As a LINQ lover, I would do it like:

```
var result = (myObjects.Count(obj => obj.SendEvent()) == myObjects.Length);
```

In case you want to break the loop on the first `false` value, it coud be:

```
var result = myObjects.All(obj => obj.SendEvent());
```

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem my bad, missed that line

Comment: Hmm, personally I try to avoid using predicates that have side-effects in Linq... It can lead to surprising things if (for example) some code enumerates the result twice (of course, you should avoid enumerating `IEnumerable<T>` things multiple times in general, but still)

Comment: @MatthewWatson: Trying to grasp what you said. Can u put a quick example plz? Also, how will that affect a regular `for` loop?

Comment: @dotNET: I think here it does not matter, but what Matthew is probably trying to say is that if you have something like: `somelist.Where(x => SideEffect(x))` then the `.Where` will be evaluated lazily. As a result you don't know when the `SideEffect` will be called, this can resulting in unpredictable behavior. It can take days before the `SideEffect` is eventually called for some `x` and then the call might be outdated, etc. Usually it is always good practice to avoid too many side-effect functions anyway.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem: Thanks a lot. I see the issue now.