# Simple substitute of assignment operators of logical ones in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, operators, logical-operators, assignment-operator, substitution

JavaScript has [assignment operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators) corresponding to [arithmetic](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators) ones: `+=`, `-=`, `*=`, `/=`, `%=`.

JavaScript also has [assignment operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators) corresponding to [bitwise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators) ones: `<<=`, `>>=`, `>>>=`, `&=`, `^=`, `|=`.

But it doesn't have [assignment operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators) corresponding to [logical](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators) ones: `||=`, `&&=`.

Then, I can't do things like

```
aVeryLongVariableIdontWantToRepeat ||= 1;
```

In [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2324549/why-doesnt-java-have-compound-assignment-versions-of-the-conditional-and-and-co) it's explained why <del>JS</del> Java doesn't have such operators. I guess it's the same for JS.

But I want to know if there is a simple way to emulate them, avoiding

```
aVeryLongVariableIdontWantToRepeat = aVeryLongVariableIdontWantToRepeat || 1;
```

Comment: What about simply shortening your variable names?

Comment: The other question you link to isn't about JavaScript, it's about Java.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Oh, true

Comment: @p.s.w.g I can't shorten things like `CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype.clear`

Comment: @Oriol `var p = CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype; p.clear = p.clear || ...`?

Comment: I've often thought the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there isn't. I feel like there should be more to this answer, but really, that's it. The shortest version of `a = a || x` is ... `a = a || x`.

Comment: There's also `a = a? a : x`, but that's a tad longer.

Answer (score 1):

It might help you to investigate writing your code using Coffeescript, which has the ||= operator available.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a shorter way: `a = a || 1` is the simplest way to do it.

However, to avoid unnecessary assignment of values (slightly at the expense of readability) you can also do `a || ( a = 1)`.

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/v8xGL/)

```
var a,b='x';
a || ( a = 1 );
b || ( b = 2 );
console.log( a + ', ' + b ); // Outputs "1, x"
```

Comment: Of course, `a || (a = 1)` is no shorter than `a = a || 1` and we can count on the engine not to waste time on dead assignments.